# Filter Array by Multiple Criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I'm looking to filter the following array:

```
const array = 
[{city: "Fullerton", techName: ["Sean"], routeName: ["Route 1"], routeDay: "Monday"},
{city: "Long Beach", techName: ["Sean", "Greg"], routeName: ["Route 1", "Route 3"], routeDay: "Monday"}, 
{city: "Huntington Beach", techName: ["Sean"], routeName: ["Route 1"], routeDay: "Monday"}];
```

With the following array:

```
const filters = [{type: "routeDay", filter: "Monday"}, {type: "techName", filter: "Greg"}];
```

I am filtering a table with multiple filters and I cannot figure out how to filter by both filters.  I am able to filter by one or the other, but one one and the other.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Is it an OR filter you are trying to do?

Comment: Trying to do an AND filter.  Trying to filter by each filter in the filters array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter the array, and for each item use `Array.every()` to iterate the array of `filters`, and check if the values are acceptable.

Get the relevant value by `type` from the current object. If it's an array check if it contains the `filter`'s value. If not compare value and `filter`.

```js
const array = 
[{city: "Fullerton", techName: ["Sean"], routeName: ["Route 1"], routeDay: "Monday"},
{city: "Long Beach", techName: ["Sean", "Greg"], routeName: ["Route 1", "Route 3"], routeDay: "Monday"}, 
{city: "Huntington Beach", techName: ["Sean"], routeName: ["Route 1"], routeDay: "Monday"}];

const filters = [{type: "routeDay", filter: "Monday"}, {type: "techName", filter: "Greg"}];


const result = array.filter(o => filters.every(({ type, filter }) => {
  const value = o[type];
  
  return Array.isArray(value) ? value.includes(filter) : value === filter;
}));

console.log(result);
```